# Positioning images to fit all size screens

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with positioning images,I need to position a lot images over another larger background image.

An image Like this
[image]

I have tried Absolute but it does not keep the position of the image say I wanted to put a clip art image of a board pin over the background image and need it pointing at a sun and when it's clicked I get a popup dialog,
but then when I change the size of the emulator screen the clip art image is not at the same position I wanted it on the background image.

I first tried just putting the clip art on it with a image editor and used onTouch Listener but that didn't work out when I changed the size of the screen with the x and y coordinates.  And tried Absolute Layout and that doesn seem to keep the position.

any ideas would help me big time thanks

Answer (score 1):

AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, so it's probably best to use relative layout alongside with dp.

Answer (score 0):

You could use relative layout so you can use `layout_below="@id/view1"`, `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view2"`, and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view3"`. You can also use `android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"`, `android:layout_marginRight="10dip"`, `android:layout_marginTop="10dip"`, and `android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"` to move the views left/right and up/down relative to their current positions. There is also ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, and ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) for more properties.

Comment: But I need to keep the image in the same position when the size of the screen is changed from 2.7inch to 10.1inch.

Comment: It will be kept in the same position. For example, if the screen (2.7in) is 10dip to the right of the left side of the screen, it will still be 10dip right of the left side of the screen at 10.1 inches.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually calculate visible width and height of the image by using its drawable's  `getIntrinsicHeight()` and `getIntrinsicWidth()` and then set Image's `scaleType` to `FIT_XY` (this saves image's ratio, and also makes its size correct, while `FIT_CENTER` does not).